# Prove the uniformly continuity of a function with a certain property

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove this:

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and has the property that for each $\epsilon >0$ there is $M>0$ such that if $|x| \ge M$, then $|f(x)|< \epsilon$.Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

**And I am stuck in how to find the $\delta$ that works no matter the point, I dont know how to use the propety and the continuity right to get the result.Thank you I am a little worry because I dont know how to attack this problems.**

Comment: Do you know that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Yes :) we have the result

Comment: For a fixed /epsilon , consider [-M-1,M+1], f is uniformly continuous in it since it is compact. Then there exist a /delta < 1 such that ...

Comment: and Am I done with that consideration ?

Comment: I think I have to argue it deferent or Can I say it like that ?

Comment: @Sky When do you use the property?

Comment: To choose a delta needed just word-by-word from the definition of u.c..

Comment: I dont understand you :) Im a litle bit confused :) Im sorry

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon >0$, by assuming, there is $M>0$ such that  if $|x| \ge M$, then $|f(x)|<\frac \epsilon 2$. As we know, $f(x)$ is uniformaly continuous on the compact interval $[-M-1,M+1]$, so for the given $\epsilon$, there exists $\delta>0$, and $\delta<1$, such that for any $x_1, x_2 \in  [-M-1,M+1]$, when $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$, we have $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$.

If $|x_1-x_2|<\delta<1$, then there are following cases:

1. $x_1, x_2 \in  [-M-1,M+1]$. It is obvious that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|< \epsilon $.
2. $x_1, x_2 \notin  [-M-1,M+1]$. So $|x_1|, |x_2|\ge M$, and hence $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le |f(x-1)|+|f(x_2)| \le \frac \epsilon 2+\frac \epsilon 2=\epsilon $.
3. $x_1\in  [-M-1,M+1]$ and  $x_2 \notin  [-M-1,M+1]$. Since $\delta<1$,  $|x_1|, |x_2|\ge M$, and hence $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le |f(x-1)|+|f(x_2)| \le \frac \epsilon 2+\frac \epsilon 2=\epsilon $.
4. $x_2\in  [-M-1,M+1]$ and  $x_1 \notin  [-M-1,M+1]$. Since $\delta<1$,  $|x_1|, |x_2|\ge M$, and hence $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le |f(x-1)|+|f(x_2)| \le \frac \epsilon 2+\frac \epsilon 2=\epsilon $.

May it helps!

Comment: I think it is all isnt :) @Paul :) then we are done isnt it ?

Comment: In the second case it should be $x_1$ not $x-1$ isn it?

Comment: We are done with this isn't? :)

Comment: @user162343: Yes, It is all. There are four cases: the two points both in the interval $[-M-1,M+1]$; or they both are not in interval $[-M-1,M+1]$; or one is in but the other is not in.